# Transaction Error

Tags: php, mysql, transactions

I need help getting this snippet of transaction code to work as expected. It seems I'm not placing the BEGIN and COMMIT correctly. The balance should increase/decrease whenever an amount is added/subtracted, but it does not.

```
<?php
require_once 'login.php';
$db_server = mysql_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password);
if (!$db_server) die("Unable to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db_database, $db_server)
or die("Unable to select database: " . mysql_error());

if(isset($_POST['amount']))
{
    if(isset($_POST['ADD']) && $number !="")  
    {
          mysql_query("BEGIN"); 
          $query="UPDATE accounts SET balance=balance+amount WHERE number='12345'"; 
    }
    else
    {
          $query="UPDATE accounts SET balance='balance-amount' WHERE number='12345'";
          mysql_query($query);     
    }

  if($query){
     mysql_query("COMMIT");
  }
  else{
    mysql_query("ROLLBACK");
  }

}

echo <<<_END
<form action='transaction.php' method="post"><pre>
Enter the amount: <input type="text" name="amount" />
<input type="submit" value="ADD VALUE" />   <input type="submit" value="SUBTRACT VALUE" />
</pre></form>
_END;

$query="SELECT balance FROM accounts WHERE number='12345'";
$result=mysql_query($query);
$rows=mysql_num_rows($result);

for($j=0; $j<$rows; ++$j)
{ 
   $row=mysql_fetch_row($result);
echo <<<_END
   <pre>
Your current balance is $row[$j]
   </pre>
_END;

}


echo <<<_END
<form action="transaction.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="ADD" value="yes" />
<input type="hidden" name="SUBTRACT" value="yes" />
</pre></form>
_END;

mysql_close($db_server);

 ?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: following up from what @Truth said, it's worth pointing out that the PDO extension has built-in support for transactions.

Comment: Thank you so much, Spudley. I would go through the tutorial and leanr about it.

Answer (score 2):

You code is pretty ugly and not OK. For example you are not setting `amount` in query, if you post `ADD` nothing will happen, if it's not `ADD` the code `'balance-amount'` is not ok as it should be `balance-$amount`, `$number` is not set anywhere, etc ...

Try with PDO please, as `mysql_*` functions are deprecated ...

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$db_hostname.';dbname='.$db_database, $db_username, $db_password, array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false));

if(isset($_POST['amount']) && ($_POST['amount'] != '') && ($_POST['number'] != '')){

    if($_POST['type'] == 'ADD')  {
        $query = "UPDATE `accounts` SET `balance`=`balance`+:amount WHERE `number`=:number"; 
    } else {
        $query = "UPDATE `accounts` SET `balance`=`balance`-:amount WHERE `number`=:number";
    }

    try {

        $db->beginTransaction();

        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute(array(':amount' => $_POST['amount'], ':number' => $_POST['number']));

        $db->commit();

    } catch(PDOException $ex) {
        $db->rollBack();
        echo $ex->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Another error is in your form, you are not sending anything, try with this:

```
echo <<<_END
<form action='transaction.php' method="post"><pre>
Enter the amount: <input type="text" name="amount" /> <br />
Number: <input type="text" name="number" value="12345" /><br />
Type: <select name="type"><option value="ADD">ADD</option><option value="SUBSTRACT">SUBSTRACT</option></select>
<input type="submit" value="Make changes" />
</pre></form>
_END;
```

And to get info:

```
$stmt = $db->query(SELECT `balance` FROM `accounts` WHERE `number`='12345');
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo "<pre>Your current balance is ".$row['balance']."</pre>";
```

Comment: Hi Mihai, Thanks for the help, but this part is not understandeable yet. try {          $db->beginTransaction();          $stmt = $db->prepare($query);         $stmt->execute(array(':amount' => $_POST['amount'], ':number' => $number));          $db->commit();      } catch(PDOException $ex) {         $db->rollBack();         echo $ex->getMessage();     }

Comment: I've updated my post as you have errors in form too. You have no choice as later you will not be able to use `mysql_*` functions, it's not that hard, basically it's same but more elegant. Try this [TUTORIAL](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers). It's easy to understand.

Comment: The `try`, `catch` blocks are for your safety and for debugging. It will `TRY` to make transaction, prepare the query, binds params, executes it and commits. If that fails it will `CATCH` the exception, it will rollback the transaction and show you what errors it encountered.

Comment: Much appreciated, Miahai. I learned a lot from your post. But i really need to study the link you provided, and hopefully, it will clear many mistakes.

Comment: Best of luck, have a nice evening/day.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the sequences of assignments and executions:

- If ADD is set, you do BEGIN, create a query string, but never execute it.
- If ADD is not set, you don't do BEGIN but you do create and execute the query.

Both are somewhat wrong.  In all cases, `$query` is set so you always ROLLBACK, but you have not always started the transaction.

You need something more like:

```
if (isset($_POST['amount']))
{
    mysql_query("BEGIN"); 
    if (isset($_POST['ADD']) && $number !="")  
    {
        $query="UPDATE accounts SET balance=balance+amount WHERE number='12345'"; 
    }
    else
    {
        $query="UPDATE accounts SET balance='balance-amount' WHERE number='12345'";
    }
    mysql_query($query);     

    if (...query succeeded...)
    {
        mysql_query("COMMIT");
    }
    else
    {
        mysql_query("ROLLBACK");
    }
}
```

I'm not certain how you detect that the query worked; you may need to capture and examine the value returned by `mysql_query()`.

At some point you're going to have to revisit the fact that you subtract the amount from the balance when ADD is set but the number is an empty string.  But you're also going to need to fix the repeated `'12345'` at the same time.  If the number is not set, you probably shouldn't be doing anything in the DB; you should just be rejecting the request altogether.

---

PS: I think the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated.  Use PDO instead.

Remember to avoid [SQL Injection](http://xkcd.com/327) — which is much harder to do with the `mysql_*` functions than with PDO.

Comment: Thank you, Jonathan. I think i just need to learn PDO in order to get this done. I am still learning the interation between Mysql and PHP, then i just thought of trying something like Transaction out, but my mistakes reveal i need learning PDO to get this done. Thank You for the educative input.

Comment: I agree that you need to learn PDO (me too — PDO wasn't in PHP 3).